# Having issues accessing files in packaged boxes in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to access files contained in box packages created with

```
vagrant package
```

Creating the boxes is no problem and I can open them with a something like 7-Zip to reveal the vmdk file inside, but, they don't seem to contain the same files I see in a vmdk downloaded from the Vagrant box repository.

For instance, this is the file structure of an Ubuntu box downloaded from the repository:

[image: vmdk file listing]

It looks like a regular Linux file system and I can extract any files I want.

And this is the vmdk of a box made with Vagrant package:

[image: vmdk file listing]

and the 0.img file:

[image: vmdk file listing]

Now I can drill down into some of those but the folders and files are not organised in the same way as the regular listing above. But in particular ***I can't see any sign of the folders and files I've created within the box*** which are certainly packaged by Vagrant package since that's its function.

I'm on Windows and some of those listed files I can't get into such as the System.map which may hold the gold I'm after.

So, my questions are:

- where would I expect to find the files I'm after?
- is it possible to package a Vagrant box so it has a regular file system output as in boxes downloaded from the repository?
- also, the 1.lvm file listed is a massive 42GB which I can't quite extract to my current drive. Is that likely to be important to my quest? I can't seem to look inside it without extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing a representation of the entire disk in 7-Zip. Your experience when opening disk images with 7-Zip may differ, based on the partitioning scheme, partition types, and file systems used on the disk.

7-Zip understands various partitioning schemes (e.g. MBR, APM, GPT), various partition types, and file systems (e.g. FAT, NTFS, EXT2, EXT3). 7-Zip at this time does not handle Logical Volume Manager (LVM) partitions. You can [extract that LVM partition and mount it](http://www.uni-koeln.de/~pbogusze/posts/Extract_files_from_VMDK_images.html) on a Linux machine to see the files you're expecting.

So to answer your questions directly:

1. In partition #1, (`1.lvm`)
2. Sure, change your disk configuration prior to packaging it up.
3. Yes, for the above reasons